# Sinatra test with sessions and concurrent access

Tags: ruby, session, sinatra, rack

I wanted to write a little tests that concurrently accesses my little sinatra app.

The problem here is, that I use sessions (via Rack::Session::Pool). I could not figure out how to let rack-test spawn a new session. Whe I inject session data in my request, I always end up with one session. So I can basically have only 1 session at a time.

In my test I tried the following:

```
threads = []
2.times do |index|
  threads << Thread.new do
    get "/controller/something", {}, "rack.session" => {:id => "Thread#{index}"}
    post "/do_action"
  end
end
thrads.each{|t| t.join}
```

Is there some kind of "Browser-Layer where I can have multiple instances"?

EDIT: I am sorry I have to clarify: The threading example was just a wild guess to get a new session. It didn't work. So I'm just looking for a way to open multiple sessions on a runnin (test)server. In development mode I can just open a new browser session to achieve such a thing. In test mode I'm currently lost.

Comment: @leify what is that you want that can be done with unicorn .sorry correct if I'm wrong Sinatra work on webrick and webrick are basically single thread so I dont see that happening correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: That may be right, but it has nothing to do with the problem. The threading example is from the client side. Even if the server only has one thread, it should be able to manage multiple sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example using MiniTest with the Spec syntax extensions.

```
# using MiniTest::Spec extensions
# http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Spec.html

describe 'Fun with Sinatra and multiple sessions' do
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    Sinatra::Application
  end

  it "does some stuff with multiple sessions" do
    sess1 = Rack::Test::Session.new(Rack::MockSession.new(app))
    sess2 = Rack::Test::Session.new(Rack::MockSession.new(app))
    sess1.wont_equal sess2

    sess1.get '/' # or whatever
    sess1.last_response.must_equal :ok?

    sess2.get '/' # or whatever
    sess2.last_response.must_equal :ok?
  end

  it "this does the same thing" do
    sess2 = Rack::Test::Session.new(Rack::MockSession.new(app))

    get '/' # or whatever
    last_response.must_equal :ok?

    sess2.get '/' # or whatever
    sess2.last_response.must_equal :ok?

  end

end
```